# Update Javascript nested Object one by one

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of object:

```
  {
   a:{name:'a'},
   b:{name:'b'},
   c:{name:'c'},
}
```

And my goal is to add new key/value pair to each object. So final result shall look like this:

```
 {
   a:{name:'a',newField:false},
   b:{name:'b',newField:false},
   c:{name:'c',newField:false},
}
```

So far I've tried to put my current object into array and loop through but I had no success at all since I am getting only first level of key/value pairs.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Iterate through `Object.values(yourObject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this it to use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```js
const data = {
  a: { name: 'a' },
  b: { name: 'b' },
  c: { name: 'c' },
};

for (let key in data) {
  data[key].newField = false;
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you do not wish to mutate the data you can try the following:

```js
const data = {
  a: { name: 'a' },
  b: { name: 'b' },
  c: { name: 'c' },
};

const copy = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) =>
  [key, { ...val, newField : false }]));

console.log(copy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I thought about that but isnt this line   data[key].newField = false; considered as mutation?

Comment: @Roffybc I added a non-mutated example.

Comment: Thank you very much I will be able to accept ur answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy mutating the object rather than creating a new one use a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement).

```js
const obj = {
 a: {name:'a'},
 b: {name:'b'},
 c: {name:'c'},
};

for (let key in obj) {
  obj[key].newField = false;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I was about to post your own answer .. XD

Answer (score 1):

a for..in should do it

```
for (const key in yourObject) {
  yourObject[key].newField = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```js
const orig_obj = {
   a:{name:'a'},
   b:{name:'b'},
   c:{name:'c'},
};

Object.keys(orig_obj).forEach((key) =>{
  orig_obj[key].newField = false;
});

console.log(orig_obj);
// Output:
/*
{
   a:{name:'a',newField:false},
   b:{name:'b',newField:false},
   c:{name:'c',newField:false},
}
*/
```